# c++/cli winforms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
mainform ^ main = gcnew mainform;
main->Show();
```

У меня есть две формы, при нажатии на кнопку, появляется другая, при этом первая прячется, как сделать что бы при закрытии второй формы, закрывалась и первая, потому что если просто ее спрятать и закрыть вторую форму, первая останется открытая(просто ее не будет видно).
`this->Close();` не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*как сделать что бы при закрытии второй формы, закрывалась и первая

Например, из второй формы завершить работу всей программы:

```
private:System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^sender,System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    // successful, exitcode = 0
    Environment.Exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: функция exit помогла